# Acknowledgement on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to show a acknowledgement (more precisely a popup) when form is successfully submitted.Previously I was using Ajax to validate form and display pop up but now I want to achieve same **without Ajax**.
Is there any event in javascript/Jquery which is invoked after successful form submission? or Is there any other alternative available?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT 1 :**
I am using Spring 3.0.
Here is the detailed scenario
1. User fill the form and click on submit
2. Request will be sent to controller (Server side)
3. Validation will be done at server side
4. If errors are present I am using Spring validation to show it and goto Step 1
5. else successfully submit the form and show a popup.
6. After user clicks on popup redirect to other page.

---

**EDIT 2:**
I am completely agree with the opinion that Ajax is the right/best way to do it and I already implemented it using Ajax. But client want to use non-ajax approach and I cannot go beyond his words.

Comment: Posting without AJAX is a round trip to the server. The page reloads. There is no alternative to that. So, are you looking for a modal on page-rerender or are you looking to block the UI as the form is being submitted to say "Please wait while we submit your data"?

Comment: @Splash-X: I want to show a notification like `Form is successfully submitted.`

Comment: What server side language are you using? Regardless of the language you would need to build that in to the page you render after the form is submitted. If you choose to reload the same page they just submitted and display a message bubble thats your choice. The type of plugin you wish to use will depend on how you want the message to be displayed. If you want a modal you could use jQuery UI Modal, Fancybox or event BlockUI. You also have the option of using your server side language to just render out a div, p or lable with your message.

Comment: you could redirect after submit to a page saying that, but that is all serverside

Comment: @Splash-X: Do you mean I should add modal or something on other page on which I am redirecting after submit?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: Can you add something more, as I am bit confused how to achieve it on server side.

Comment: Sorry I am not a spring guy. But basically, I'm sure you know how to setup a redirect from the server. So basically you put in a catch for that form posting to the server, and then issue a redirect to a new page featuring, thank you copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question piqued my curiosity, as I was trying to do something similar *using* the iframe solution [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9093197/751450) by Leon. Eventually I succeeded, however, I would like to suggest that rather than using a direct `onload` property, you make use of the [jQuery `.load()` event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) on the iframe.

**Edit:** So here's how I set up the form (using HTML5, so quotes aren't necessary):

```
<div id=message></div> /* Example-specific, see below */

<form method=post action=backend.php target=iframe>
    // Form data here
</form>

<iframe name=iframe></iframe>
```

I added the following CSS code to hide the iframe:

```
iframe {
    border:0px;
    height:0px;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0px;
}
```

Don't use `display:none`, as some browsers will refuse to submit to an element that's not displayed.

Then in my [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) JavaScript...

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
  // Your load event here.
});
```

You could also change that about, so that it specifically only triggers after a specific event (if you're using dynamic forms, for example). In such a case, you may want to use `.unbind('load')` before `.load()` to prevent previously-added `.load()` functions from calling.

Now when the form is submitted, it loads into the hidden iframe. When the iframe loads the page (backend.php, in my example), it triggers the `.load()` function. In my specific case, I set up a `<div id=message>` to display a message:

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
    $('#message').html('The form successfully submitted.');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Can you please add some more information about how you did it?

Comment: I've added some more coding details, as well as my specific example for how I acknowledged the form's submission. Note that the backend page loaded into the iframe doesn't even need any content returned unless you particularly need it. As long as it returns, the code will trigger once the form has submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Without Ajax? No Problem - let's go back to how the Web really used to work in the past ;-)

Since I am getting you don't want to refresh the current page, how about this approach:

1. have a hidden iframe on the same page, with a name & id
2. point the target property of your form to the name given in the previous step
3. submitting the form will now be "hidden"
4. you can have an onload property on the iframe set to a javascript method of your liking to get called once the form finished submitting
5. that javascript code could also retrieve the contents of the iframe and check for your server-side response (maybe even including an error msg)
6. notify the user about the result

This is all fairly easy to setup, let us know how it works for ya..

Comment: Submitting to a hidden iframe? That *is* Ajax.

Comment: Submitting to hidden iframe is NOT AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which language you are coding in.
One option - use javascript.

On the submit button onclick event (client side event), perform the page validation and display alert pop up, if the page is valid.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSubmitClientClick() {
        Page_ClientValidate();
        if (Page_IsValid) {
             alert('Form has been successfully submitted.');
            return true;
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: I am using server side validations.

Comment: You can still do the server side validation. This will do a client side validation first on submit, display pop up if the page is valid and then do the server side validation.

Comment: Please check my edit. I want to show popup after server side validation.

Comment: You can use Jquery Form Plugin. Use the success callback to load the response into a fancybox. [link](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be wise to throw up a message saying the submission was successful just *before* the submission is attempted.

Comment: The jQuery form plugin *does* use Ajax, that's the point of it.

Comment: @Quentin I agree with your comment about the message.  I could see showing a modal, like a $.blockUI (jQuery BlockUI plugin) with a message of "Please wait while we submit your request" on a non-ajax form but it's all about wording. You should never says "Your form has been submitted" before the form is submitted, processed and any server validation errors are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to drop AJAX approach? Without AJAX, server side validation implies page reload. On page reload you would lose client side (JS) state.

One alternative is to use hidden frame/iframe/a new window to perform server side validation on form submit(possibly use the pop up you are referring to in your question). Which in my opinion is not the right approach(A BIG NO). You may rather stick to AJAX or go with non AJAX way of form submit.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am completely agree with it, I already implemented it in same way but client replied with A BIG NO and asked (ordered) me to remove it.